# while setting the span element height as 100% it is not set as parent Div height

Tags: html, css

I am having two div elements. Between them I have a `span` element. The parent `div` element height is not given. But the height of `parentDiv` is calculated based on content of the `div`. But the `span` element height also set as 100%. But height of `span` element set as zero. Please refer the below code.

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <span id="spanelement"></span>
    <div id="child2"></div>
</div>

<style>
    #spanelement{
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
    }
</style>
```

Can anyone suggest me how to overcome this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the parent is not 100%.

Try this-

```
body
{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
html
{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
}
.parentdiv
{
height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`<span>` elements are inline.
You need to make it `display: block;`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set **height** and **width** of an empty SPAN element.
Anyhow you can use **padding** instead of **height** and **width** 
or use `display:block;`